# Tablix Row Custom Message

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Based on Some Condition on my Dataset,Rather than showing the row with Fields mapped,I want to Show a Custom Text Message.is there any property to do this?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS has a built-in field for dealing with empty datasets which allows you to replace a tablix with a preset message.  If you select your table and view the Properties pane on the right-hand side, it's under the "No Rows" section, "No Rows Message".

Alternatively, you can use a custom solution by evaluating the dataset's contents and hiding/showing a text box accordingly.

[Example of custom message](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/c69e9487-1bed-4689-ad4f-dd048e8defd7/)

If you need to perform the operation row by row, you could add an extra row within your grouping (meaning it repeats for every row) which could contain your text message, set to hidden and then add a row visibility expression that shows the row based on your condition.